# How can i redirect HTTP requests to custom port to HTTPS/443 via Apache2?

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to configure apache2 for a specific use case. An old web server only runs in HTTP on port 8788. I want to put it behind an apache reverse-proxy (Debian) which will ensure the encryption of exchanges with the client and will make requests to the web server in HTTP/port 8788.

The reverse proxy already works for other web servers and i changed the DNS for oldserver.example.com to point to the reverse-proxy IP address.

Connections to http://oldserver.example.com and https://oldserver.example.com work correctly and display the old server's web page.

But when I try to access http://oldserver.example.com:8788 (I have to keep this access via port 8788 because the link has been posted like this for years) the browser redirects to https://oldserver.example.com:8788 and shows this error:

[Secure Connection Failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBkza.png)

In the configuration files and logs below, I replaced the reverse proxy IP address with X.X.X.X; the IP address of the oldserver by Y.Y.Y.Y and the IP addresses of the clients by Z.Z.Z.Z.

When I try with wget, everything seems OK:

```
wget -v http://oldserver.example.com:8788
--2022-09-14 14:36:15--  http://oldserver.example.com:8788/
Resolving oldserver.example.com (oldserver.example.com)... X.X.X.X
Connecting to oldserver.example.com (oldserver.example.com)|X.X.X.X|:8788... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: https://oldserver.example.com/ [following]
--2022-09-14 14:36:15--  https://oldserver.example.com/
Connecting to oldserver.example.com (oldserver.example.com)|X.X.X.X|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 11628 (11K) [text/html]
Saving to: 'index.html'

index.html.3                                        100%[=================================================================================================================>]  11.36K  --.-KB/s    in 0s

2022-09-14 14:36:15 (42.0 MB/s) - 'index.html' saved [11628/11628]
```

### Configuration files

/etc/apache2/sites-available/oldserver.conf :

```
<VirtualHost *:80 *:8788>
    ServerName oldserver.example.com
    include /etc/apache2/xyz/general.conf
    include /etc/apache2/xyz/redirect-ssl.conf
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error_oldserver.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access_oldserver.log combined
</VirtualHost>


<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost *:443>
            ServerName oldserver.example.com

            ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error_oldserver.log
            CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access_oldserver.log combined

            include /etc/apache2/xyz/general.conf
            include /etc/apache2/xyz/ssl.conf
            include /etc/apache2/xyz/revproxy.conf
            ProxyPass / http://Y.Y.Y.Y:8788/
            ProxyPassreverse / http://Y.Y.Y.Y:8788/
    </Virtualhost>
</IfModule>
```

/etc/apache2/xyz/general.conf :

```
ServerAdmin system@example.com
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
Protocols h2 http/1.1
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
ErrorDocument 500 https://reverseproxy.example.com/
ErrorDocument 503 https://reverseproxy.example.com/
```

/etc/apache2/xyz/redirect-ssl.conf :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

/etc/apache2/xyz/revproxy.conf :

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyRequests Off
SSLProxyEngine on
```

/etc/apache2/xyz/ssl.conf:

```
#####▒| SSL #####

SSLEngine on
Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000"

SSLCertificateFile      /etc/ssl/wildcard.example.com.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile   /etc/ssl/wildcard.example.com.key

<FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</FilesMatch>
<Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Directory>
BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
        nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
        downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown
```

### Logs

Strangely, on the reverse proxy, I have nothing in the /var/log/apache2/error_oldserver.log file but I find traces of the connections in the /var/log/apache2/error.log file:

```
error.log:[Wed Sep 14 14:43:53.497291 2022] [proxy_http:error] [pid 36806:tid 139808714381056] (20014)Internal error (specific information not available): [client Z.Z.Z.Z:51225] AH01102: error reading status line from remote server Y.Y.Y.Y:8788, referer: https://oldserver.example.com/
```

I don't have access to the logs of the oldserver.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: If anyone comes across this post with the same problem, here is the solution I implemented.

There were two problems:
- for the redirect from http://oldserver.example.com:8788 to https://oldserver.example.com, I configured a rewrite rule (RewriteCond and RewritRule).
- for the redirection from http://oldserver.example.com:8788 which was done automatically to https://oldserver.example.com:8788, it was the HSTS of my configuration that was causing the problem. Since I redirect connections to HTTPS with the rewrite rule above, I was able to disable it and everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Add new block with port  *:8788  in the same virtual host and add LISTEN 8788 in the same block in virtual host file. And port should be opened from Security Group.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName oldserver.example.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/oldserver.example.com/public

<Directory /var/www/oldserver.example.com>
        Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
</Directory>

      ErrorLog /var/www/oldserver.example.com/error.log
      CustomLog /var/www/oldserver.example.com/access.log combined

SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateKeyFile /SSL Certificate path/xxx.pem
SSLCertificateFile /SSL Certificate path/xxx.pem
SSLCertificateChainFile /SSL Certificate path/xxx.pem

</VirtualHost>

LISTEN 8788
<VirtualHost *:8788>
ServerName oldserver.example.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/oldserver.example.com/public

<Directory /var/www/oldserver.example.com>
        Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
</Directory>

SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateKeyFile /SSL Certificate path/xxx.pem
SSLCertificateFile /SSL Certificate path/xxx.pem
SSLCertificateChainFile /SSL Certificate path/xxx.pem

</VirtualHost>
```